# Python - How can I make a log file invisible and have it sent to my Email

Tags: python

So i created a logger and it saves the log file to wherever the .pyw file is and i was wondering if i could make it save the log file at a different location or make it invisible. I'm thinking that it would be better to save it at a different location since I want to send the log file to my Email every 15-20 minutes. 
Using Python 2.7.8

Comment: what logging sysstem do you use? the standard logging module?

Comment: Please show your effort by explaining what you have tried so far and why it isn't working as excepted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you used the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module from standard library, you can change the location of this log file like this:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='<full-location-here>',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

For making the file invisible, on a UNIX system you can always make the filename start with a '.' or if you're on windows, may be you can use third-party modules like [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to achieve the same (I am not sure about this part though).

Or alternatively, you can use [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) library to create a temporary file like object and send it. For sending the mail, use a module like [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html).

Also, read the docs.

Comment: You use IMAP to read/modify the content of an IMAP account, to send mail you use SMTP.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Oops... my bad! Edited it. :)

Comment: That's not really properly invisible, though, just obscure. If saving it in a location where only you have read and execute permission is insufficiently secure, it would be better to avoid the file system altogether.

Comment: @tripleee: That's true. I mentioned this because the OP was asking for creation of an "invisible" file (not sure what they meant by 'invisible' in this context), and these were the ways I could think of.

Comment: I changed the directory of the log file but I still can't find a way to send it to my email automatically. Anyone have the code for that. Didn't work when I tried it on my own and haven't been able to find a solution on the internet.